# Return multiple values in C#

Tags: c#

How can I return multiple values from a class in C# I tried in the below way but it didn't work for me.

```
protected static string setvalues;
public static string myfunction()
{
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM category", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            setvalues = dr[0].ToString();
        }
        con.Close();
        return setvalues.ToString();
}
```

I have the following in Categories table

```
Mobiles
Laptops
Cloths
DVD players
Televisions
Cameras
```

Anybody please help me in building a code that can return thousands of values.

Comment: You can't just return them as a string[] ? Or make it an ienumerable and use a `yeild return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The List type in the C# language can solve above problem. With List, you do not need to manage the size on your own

```
    protected static List<string> listSetValues = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> myfunction()
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM category", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            listSetValues.Add(dr[0].ToString());
        }
        con.Close();
        return listSetValues;
    }
```

Comment: I am getting output as `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]`

Comment: You can simply import System.Collections.Generic namespace and can have access to all properties and method of List......

Answer (score 4):

You want to return a `List<String>` (or an `IEnumerable<string>` using an iterator with `yield return`)

Comment: I am sorry, I never worked any of the above that you mention. Can you please provide me with its syntax?

Comment: Doesn't .net 3 or .net 4 have a built-in tuple type so that `SELECT *` can return `Tuple<...>[]`? That is, an array of tuples instead of a vector of strings?

Comment: List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("a string");

then return the list.

Comment: @Bahamut - By trying your code I am getting output as 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'

Comment: to get the output from the list do a foreach. foreach(string strTemp in myList){ // do whatever to strTemp };

Comment: glad it helped ^^ don't forget to pick an answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Tuple class in .net 4.0. Forexample,

```
var population = new Tuple<string, int, int, int, int, int, int>(
                       "New York", 7891957, 7781984, 
                       7894862, 7071639, 7322564, 8008278);
```

OR 
    `var population = Tuple.Create("New York", 7891957, 7781984, 7894862, 7071639, 7322564, 8008278);`

For more information about properties and functions of Tuple class, visit [Tuple Class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)